# How do I reliably check if an attribute is defined for an object?

Tags: python, django

Sometimes I create Objects with the `x` attribute defined, sometimes I don't.

```
class Object(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to create a subset of my Objects for which `x` is not defined at a point in my app:

```
[o for o in os if not hasattr(o,'x')]
```

I've being playing around in the shell, and I don't get the results I want.

```
>>> o = Object()
>>> o.save()
>>> o.id
1L
>>> hasattr(o,'x')
True
```

Is checking `x == None` sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, checking `x is None` is sufficient.

Any instance of `Object` will always have the attribute `x`, regardless of whether you set it - it'll just be `None` if you didn't set it.

Comment: It should be done with ``x is None``, see (PEP 8)[http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37]